# Send play/pause music from my android car stereo to my connected phone

Tags: android, react-native, android-bluetooth

I have an android car stereo which has a seperate bluetooth app which controls the audio playback from a connected device. I am building a seperate app which runs on the car stereo which should have buttons to play/pause the audio from my phone.The problem is that I cannot play/pause the music from my app.

I have tried this approach but I am only able to control other music apps such as YouTube Music with this code:

```
package com.dashcam;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.session.PlaybackState;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class MediaModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    MediaModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MediaModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void playPauseMedia() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
            KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
        }
    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void skipToNextTrack() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void skipToPreviousTrack() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS));
            audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS));
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getPlaybackState(Promise promise) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            int playbackState = audioManager.isMusicActive() ? PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING : PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED;
            promise.resolve(playbackState);
        } else {
            promise.reject("AUDIO_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", "Audio service unavailable");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to send commands to my phone to play/pause the music from my seperate app?

I tried using AudioManager to send the commands to control the music playback but that only works on music players such as YouTube Music not with the bluetooth app.